# Script para cambiar una variable SESSION

Tags: php

Lo que quiero es que al ejecutar un script me cambie una variable de SESSION

En el ejemplo que os pongo, la variable de SESSION no cambia. Siempre queda en cerrado y debería cambiar a la inscripción abierta.

'periodoinscripcion.php'

```
<?php 

session_start();


$inscripcioncerrada = "inscripcion.php"; // INSCRIPCION CERRADA
$inscripcionabierta = "registrar.php"; // INSCRIPCION ABIERTA

$_SESSION['estadoInscripcion'] = $inscripcioncerrada; // PERIODO DE INSCRIPCION 


if (isset($_REQUEST["estado"])) {
$_SESSION['estadoInscripcion'] = $_REQUEST['estado']; 
}

?>
```

y en 'periodosinscripcion_abrir_registro.php'

```
<script language="javascript">

    var nuevoEstado = '$inscripcionabierta'; 
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

    xhr.open('POST', 'periodoinscripcion.php'); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
    xhr.send(encodeURI('estado=' + nuevoEstado));

</script>
```

Comment: Es que aquí: `$inscripcionabierta = "registrar.php";` tu variable no adquiere ningún valor que haya en el archivo `registrar.php`, como parece que quieres. Ahí la variable tiene este valor: `registrar.php`, puedes hacer un `echo` de ella y lo verás. **Si quieres tener el valor de la variable `$inscripcionabierta` en el contexto**,  debes hacer un `include('registrar.php');` al principio. Entonces sí, si este archivo tiene una variable `$inscripcionabierta` **la tendrás en el contexto**, o sea, cuando usas `include` es como pegar dos trozos de papel y poder leer lo que hay en cada trozo.

Comment: Unicamente es el nombre de la pagina, tanto `registrar.php` como `inscripcion.php`. El valor es el correcto, es lo que quiero que tenga, en el caso que has puesto `$inscripcionabierta` quiero que tenga el  valor `registrar.php`

Comment: Ah ya... ¿verificaste cómo llega la petición, haciendo `var_dump($_REQUEST);`?

Comment: ¿Por qué no pasas la variable así desde el cliente: `var nuevoEstado = 'registrar.php';`? De este modo, sólo bastaría este código para cambiar la variable de sesión: `if (isset($_REQUEST["estado"])) {
$_SESSION['estadoInscripcion'] = $_REQUEST['estado']; 
}`... En todo caso, si quieres hacer echo de una variable como lo tienes ahora, creo que tienes que crearla así en el cliente: `var nuevoEstado = '<?php echo $inscripcionabierta; ?>'; `

Answer (score 0):

### El problema

Si tu código actual funciona, lo que estarás recibiendo será **una cadena igual a `$inscripcionabierta`**. Es imposible, entre otras cosas por motivos de **seguridad**, hacer valer inocentemente en el servidor una variable pasada desde el cliente. Imagínate, podríamos mandar cosas como estas al servidor y se ejecutarían:

```
var nuevoEstado='
                   function hack(){
                      echo "te estoy hackeando"; 
                      require("credenciales.php"); 
                      /*voy a sacar la contraseña*/ 
                      echo $credenciales;
                    } 

                    hack();
                  ';
```

### La solución

¿Por qué no pasas la variable así desde el cliente?:

```
var nuevoEstado = 'registrar.php';
```

De este modo, sólo bastaría este código para cambiar la variable de sesión:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["estado"])) {
    $_SESSION['estadoInscripcion'] = $_REQUEST['estado']; 
}
```

Comment: La solución no me vale. Esa variable de session se utiliza para luego poder acceder a una pagina u otra. Es decir, el usuario le da click y se ejecuta la funcion y la variable de session tiene que cambiar para siempre y tener siempre ese valor. hasta que vuelva a usar otro script similiar y que lo vuelva a cambiar. Ejemplo, si esta la inscripcion cerrada, el usuario da click en la pagina y ejecuta el script y la variable de session cambiaria a inscripcion abierta y ahi queda para todos hasta que el usuario vuelva a darle click y ejecute el script pero con el nuevo estado de inscripcion cerrada

Comment: @PaoloFrigenti no entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer. De todos modos, me parece que sería mejor enviar un valor simplemente y a partir de ese valor gestionar lo que quieras... hacerlo de otro modo sería a mi modo de ver complicarte la vida inútilmente. De todos modos, creo que la respuesta ha ayudado a dilucidar que ibas por el camino equivocado, porque no funcionaría así y por la peligrosidad que ello supondría en caso de funcionar. Es importante tener presente este criterio, para no caer en confusiones: *lo del cliente, en el cliente; lo del servidor, en el servidor*.